# upgrading gradle to 6.x error Could not set unknown property 'testClassesDir' for task ':systemtestRun' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test

Tags: java, gradle

I’m updating the gradle version of my application, it was with version 2.3 and I’m going to 6.7.1

I changed some things, of course, but this error I’m not able to resolve:

```
> Could not set unknown property 'testClassesDir' for task ':systemtestRun' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.
```

build.gradle:

```
task systemtestRun(type: Test) {
description 'run tests'
testClassesDir = sourceSets.systemtest.output.classesDirs
classpath = sourceSets.systemtest.runtimeClasspath + sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath }
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `testClassesDirs` not `testClassesDir`:

```
tasks.register('systemtestRun', Test) {
    description = 'Runs system tests.'
    group = 'verification'
    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.systemtest.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.systemtest.runtimeClasspath
}
```